# imap.gmail.com 993 - Connect fails on server but works locally

Tags: windows, email, jakarta-mail, imap, firewall

I'm running a Selenium/Cucumber tests where I'm using JavaMail API to access/read emails from a Gmail account. This all works fine locally, but the connection to imap fails when running Selenium on a TeamCity server. Seems like the computer where TeamCity is running fails to connect to port 993.

These are the tests/steps I tried:

1. Running `telnet imap.gmail.com 993` locally goes to a blank window = success, connection is established
2. The imap code in Selenium works locally every time (Windows 10)
3. Running the same Selenium script on TeamCity resulted in the following error:

```
      com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port: imap.gmail.com, 993; timeout -1
      com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port: imap.gmail.com, 993; timeout -1
      Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
```

4. I logged in to the box where TeamCity is running (Windows 10) and enabled port 993 on the Windows Firewall on outgoing connections, but that hasn't helped
5. Running `telnet imap.gmail.com 993` on the TeamCity computer results in `Connecting To imap.gmail.com...Could not open connection to the host, on port 993: Connect failed`
6. Running `openssl s_client -connect imap.gmail.com:993` on the TeamCity computer results in

```
7592:error:0200274D:system library:connect:reason(1869):../openssl-1.1.1a/crypto/bio/b_sock2.c:110:
7592:error:2008A067:BIO routines:BIO_connect:connect error:../openssl-1.1.1a/crypto/bio/b_sock2.c:111:
7592:error:0200274D:system library:connect:reason(1869):../openssl-1.1.1a/crypto/bio/b_sock2.c:110:
7592:error:2008A067:BIO routines:BIO_connect:connect error:../openssl-1.1.1a/crypto/bio/b_sock2.c:111:
connect:errno=0
```

7. I've allowed access for less secure apps on the Gmail account and tried https://accounts.google.com/b/0/DisplayUnlockCaptcha , but the simple test `telnet imap.gmail.com 993`is not affected by that anyway

This is the code used in Selenium that works locally:

```
Properties props = System.getProperties();
    props.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "imaps");
    
    Session session = Session.getInstance(props, null);
    Store store = session.getStore("imaps");
    store.connect("imap.gmail.com", email, password);
```

To sum up: The code/ imap connection works locally, but doesn't work on the server computer. Enabling an outgoing connection on port 993 in Windows Firewall hasn't helped.

Any ideas would be much appreciated, as I'm pretty stuck with this one.

Comment: I’m not sure what TeamCity is, but it’s possible that port 993 is globally firewalled, or firewalled at another level.  Can you reach port 443?

Comment: Hey Max, connecting to 443 fails as well.

Comment: Oh right, youy’d have to connect to mail.gmail.com or the like, not imap.gmail.com if you’re trying the web port.

Comment: I may be confusing teamcity with another CI thing... but IIRC it disallows outgoing connections entierly. You're supposed to use that for building/testing software, not doing anything else. Your tests should never pass or fail depending on whether some random internet site is down, see?

Comment: And the classic response is to stub the server. I've done that both in java using mockito and in ruby using factorygirl (since renamed). You'll find that your tests run both faster and more reliably when you stub remote resource.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was: External hardware firewall was blocking outgoing connections on port 993.

The issues was resolved by allowing connection on that port.